# Subcaption package: compatibility issue

Tags: packages, templates, incompatibility, subcaption

There is a compatibility problem between the [CIFA document class](http://controls.papercept.net/images/cifa/CIFA_Latex.zip)
and the *subcaption* package.
When I compile the following example (with PDFLaTex):

```
\documentclass{cifa}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\parbox{4cm}{\subcaption{This is a subcaption}\label{sub}}

\caption{nothing}
\label{nothing}
\end{figure}

See figure \ref{nothing}: there is \ref{sub} inside...

\end{document}
```

These warnings are displayed:

> Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package)
> detected,
>
> Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's
> already

In addition the words "figure" and "subfigure" are displayed
AFTER the captions.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Depending on the particulars of the `cifa` class, you may be able to restore the caption style by passing options to the `caption` package, see [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129594/8666).

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The very recent version of the `subcaption` package will even issue an error:

```
! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.
```

The only way to get around this is to specify the option `compatibility=false` to the `caption` package:

```
\documentclass{cifa}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\parbox{4cm}{\subcaption{This is a subcaption}\label{sub}}
\caption{nothing}
\label{nothing}
\end{figure}

See figure \ref{nothing}: there is \ref{sub} inside...

\end{document}
```

PLEASE NOTE: This way the customization of the captions done by the `cifa` document class will be overwritten by the `caption` package in a brute-force manner. In best case the output of the captions will look different (and some caption-related stuff offered by the `cifa` document class will not work anymore), in worst case you'll get error messages and weird output. So please also take a look at the `caption` package documentation, section "6 Package Support". Since this is a perfect method to shoot oneself in the foot, an extra warning is always issued when using the `compatibility=false` option:

```
Package caption Warning: Forced redefinition of \caption since the
(caption)                unsupported(!) package option `compatibility=false'
(caption)                was given.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

If you do not want this (or it does not work anyway) then the only solution left is not-using the `subcaption` package. Use the `subfig` package with option `caption=false` (which prevents loading of the `caption` package) instead:

```
\documentclass{cifa}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[This is a subcaption\label{sub}]{............}
\caption{nothing}
\label{nothing}
\end{figure}

See figure \ref{nothing}: there is \ref{sub} inside...

\end{document}
```