# Need help indexing subfigures: reference bugs using `subfigure` and `subcaption` not compatible with specialized document class

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, document-classes, subcaption

I'm a PhD student currently coding my dissertation into Latex.  My school developed a customized document class that they strongly recommend using for compliance with layout and formatting standards.

After employing their document class and using the subfigure package for displaying sub-figures, I discovered referencing errors after compiling the document: successive figure numbers were often incremented by 2, rather than 1, when figures comprised of subfigures were indexed.  This issue, I believe, has been described here: [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure#13631).

Next, I tested a fix (suggested here: [Subcaption package: compatibility issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/subcaption-package-compatibility-issue)) using the `\captionsetup{compatibility=false}` specifier to override document class customization of the caption package.  Application of the subcaption package and the `compatibility=false` option here did correct the indexing issue.  But, as warned, the captions were no longer formatted as specified in the document class.  It seems I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place...

My question is (finally): is there a solution that solves my indexing problem **and** permits customization of figure captions?

Any guidance on this would be very much appreciated.  Thanks for reading!

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

As requested, what follows is a minimum working example (MWE) of the indexing problem described above.  I've since discovered that figures are numbered correctly if I compile the following code using `\documentclass [11pt, twoside] {book}` instead of the customized thesis template called using `\documentclass [11pt, twoside] {uwthesis}[2012/06/19]`.  With this known, it seems the cause of the indexing problem lies somewhere in the corresponding document-class file, `uwthesis.cls`, a portion from which--containing customization of figure captions--I've posted below. The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass [11pt, twoside] {uwthesis}[2012/06/19]
%\documentclass [11pt, twoside] {book}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}  % Print the chapter and sections to the toc

\usepackage{alltt}  %
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
%\DeclareCaptionSubType*[alph]{figure}
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple,labelsep=space}
%\captionsetup{compatibility=false}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 

\newenvironment{demo}
  {\begin{alltt}\leftskip3em
     \def\\{\ttfamily\char`\\}%
     \def\{{\ttfamily\char`\{}%
     \def\}{\ttfamily\char`\}}}
  {\end{alltt}}

% metafont font.  If logo not available, use the second form
%
% \font\mffont=logosl10 scaled\magstep1
\let\mffont=\sf
% --- end-of-sample-stuff ---

\begin{document}

%
% ==========      Text pages
%

\textpages

%\include{Figures_SubcaptionsTest}
%\include{Figures_CaptionsTest}

% ================== figure 1, no subfigures
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics{//SampleFig.eps}
    \caption{Sample caption for figure 1.}
    \label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure}

% ================= figure 2,  includes subfigures
\begin{figure}[h!p]
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{//SampleSubfig.eps}
        \caption{First subfigure sample.}
        %\subcaption{First subfigure sample.}
        \label{fig:FirstSampleSubFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{//SampleSubfig.eps}
        \caption{Second subfigure sample.}
        %\subcaption{Second subfigure sample.}
        \label{fig:SecondSampleSubFig}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Sample composite caption for figure 2.}
    \label{fig:Figure2}
\end{figure}

% ================== figure 3, no subfigures
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics{//SampleFig.eps}
    \caption{Sample caption for figure 3.}
    \label{fig:Figure3}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The complete document-class file, `uwthesis.cls` (minus some comments and identifiers) is:

```
%
% Documentation is in the companion document (uwthesis.tex)
%

\ProvidesClass{uwthesis}[2012/06/19]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

%
% footnote stuff for option processing
%

\newwrite\tf@not

\newif\ifendnotes      % true if doing endnotes
  \endnotesfalse
\newif\ifchapternotes  % true if doing chapternotes
  \chapternotesfalse
\let\printchapternotes\relax
\let\printendnotes\relax

\DeclareOption{footnotes}% selects bottom-of-page notes (default)
  {}
\DeclareOption{chapternotes}% selects end-of-chapter notes
  {\chapternotestrue}
\DeclareOption{endnotes}% selects end-of-thesis notes
  {\endnotestrue}

%
% ----  Timely loading of specific packages -----------------------------
%
\newif\if@natbib      % true if including natbib
  \@natbibfalse
\DeclareOption{natbib}% includes natbib package
  {\@natbibtrue}

%
% ----  Thesis is a modified (default 12pt) book style  -----------------
%

\def\@f@ntsize{12pt}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\def\@f@ntsize{10pt}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\def\@f@ntsize{11pt}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\def\@f@ntsize{12pt}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions
\PassOptionsToClass{\@f@ntsize}{book}
\PassOptionsToClass{openany}{book}
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass{book}

\if@natbib
  \usepackage{natbib}
\fi

%
% ---- page sizes ----------------------------------------------
%
% margins are 1 inch (72pt) all around,
% except 1.5 inch (108pt) at the binding
%
% text size computed from paper size
%

\voffset -1in  % undo primitive default margins
\hoffset -1in

\topmargin 72\p@  
\headheight 12\p@
\headsep 36\p@
\oddsidemargin 108\p@ 
\evensidemargin 72\p@
\newdimen\botmargin
\botmargin 72\p@
\marginparwidth 72\p@
\marginparsep 7\p@
\footskip \z@ % set later
\footnotesep 14\p@
\parindent 1.5em

\textheight\paperheight
  \advance\textheight by-\topmargin
  \advance\textheight by-\headheight
  \advance\textheight by-\headsep
  % \advance\textheight by-\footskip
  \advance\textheight by-\botmargin
\textwidth\paperwidth
  \advance\textwidth by-\oddsidemargin
  \advance\textwidth by-\evensidemargin

% ---------------

\def\baselinestretch{1.5}    % not quite doublespaced

\setcounter{totalnumber}{5}
\setcounter{topnumber}{5}
\renewcommand\topfraction{.7}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.2}
\setlength\floatsep    {18\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\textfloatsep{30\p@ \@plus 2\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\setlength\intextsep   {20\p@ \@plus 4\p@ \@minus 4\p@}
\let\@normalsize\normalsize  % retain old definition
\setlength\abovecaptionskip{10\p@}
\setlength\belowcaptionskip{10\p@}


%
%  ----  Footnotes  ------------------------------------------
%
% Footnote placement option
%
%   [endnotes] put the references at the thesis end
%   [chapternotes] put the references at the chapter end
%   [footnotes] put the references at the page bottom
%
%   When text is written to file (.not) the source linebreaks
%   are maintained.  This keeps the individual lines in the file short.
%   Control sequences in the note text are not expanded.
%

\let\n@teitem\relax
\def\@n@teitem#1{\def\@currentlabel{#1}\item[#1]}

\def\@chapternotetext{\begingroup
  \catcode`\^^M=12\newlinechar=`\^^M
  \catcode`\\=12
  \d@chapternote}

\long\def\d@chapternote#1{%
  \immediate \write\tf@not
      {\n@teitem{\note@label} #1\relax}%
  \endgroup}

%
\def\@startnotes{%  opens the .not file
  \immediate \openout\tf@not\jobname.not\relax
  \immediate \write\tf@not{\relax}
  \setcounter{footnote}{0}}

%
% chapternotes
%

\ifchapternotes
  % \typeout{Doing chapternotes}
  \let\@footnotetext\@chapternotetext
  \@startnotes
  \def\note@label{\arabic{footnote}}
  \def\printchapternotes{% Prints the accumulated notes
    \ifnum\c@footnote>0
      \clearpage
      \begin{center} Notes to Chapter \arabic{chapter} \end{center}\par
      \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect
          \numberline{}{Notes to Chapter \arabic{chapter}}}
      \begin{description}
      \immediate\closeout\tf@not
      \catcode`@=11
      \let\n@teitem\@n@teitem
      \@input{\jobname.not}
      \end{description}
      \clearpage
      \@startnotes
    \fi
  }
  \let\old@enddocument\enddocument
  \def\enddocument{\printchapternotes\old@enddocument}
\fi

%
% endnotes
%

\ifendnotes
  % \typeout{Doing endnotes}
  \let\@footnotetext\@chapternotetext
  \@startnotes
  \def\note@label{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{footnote}}
  \def\printendnotes{% Prints the accumulated notes
    \chapter*{Notes}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Notes}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{description}
    \immediate\closeout\tf@not
    \catcode`@=11
    \let\n@teitem\@n@teitem
    \@input{\jobname.not}
    \end{description}
    \@startnotes  % allows multiple endnotes
   }
\fi

%
%  bottom-of-page footnotes format
%  full width line and hanging indent
%
\def\footnoterule{\kern-3\p@
 \hrule width \columnwidth \kern 2.6\p@}
\long\def\@makefntext#1{\parindent 1em\noindent \hangindent\parindent
 \def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
 \hb@xt@1.8em{\hss\@makefnmark}#1}

%
%  ----  Text pages  ----------------------------------
%
%  In two-sided style Chapter 1 is right handed
%
\def\textofChapter#1{\gdef\@textofChapter{#1}}  \textofChapter{Chapter}
\def\textofAppendix#1{\gdef\@textofAppendix{#1}}  \textofAppendix{Appendix}

\def\textpages{% Start of text pages
     \advance\textheight by\footskip % has to be done before the clearpage
   \clearpage
   \pagestyle{empty}
   \cleardoublepage
   \pagestyle{myheadings}\markboth{}{}
   \def\@chapapp{\protect\@textofChapter}
   \def\Thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}
   \pagenumbering{arabic}
     \footskip\z@
   }

\def\appendix{\par
 \setcounter{chapter}{0}
 \setcounter{section}{0}
 \def\@chapapp{\protect\@textofAppendix}
 \def\Thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}
 \def\thechapter{\Alph{chapter}}}


%
%  Parts
%
\def\@makeparthead#1{ \vspace*{2pc} {\centering
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \large Part \thepart \par
 \vspace{10\p@} \fi 
  \def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
  \large\bf \uppercase\expandafter{#1}\par
 \nobreak \vspace{20\p@}} }
%
\def\@makesparthead#1{ \vspace*{2pc} {\centering
 \large\bf \uppercase\expandafter{#1}\par
 \nobreak \vspace{20\p@}} }
%
\def\part{%
   \printchapternotes
   \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
   % \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \global\@topnum\z@
   \@afterindenttrue
   % \let\\\relax
   \secdef\@part\@spart}
%
%  Complication is added here to allow line breaks
%  in the part titles (via \\).
%
\def\@part[#1]#2{
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \refstepcounter{part}
  \typeout{<<\thepart>>}
  {\def\\{ }  % allow \\ in title
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\protect
     \numberline{Part\ \thepart:}#1}}\else
  {\def\\{ }  % allow \\ in title
   \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}}\fi
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}
 \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}
 \if@twocolumn
  \@topnewpage[\@makeparthead{#2}]
  \else \@makeparthead{#2}
  \@afterheading \fi}
\def\@spart#1{\if@twocolumn \@topnewpage[\@makesparthead{#1}]
  \else \@makesparthead{#1}
  \@afterheading\fi}


%
%  Chapter headings
%
\def\@makechapterhead#1{ \vspace*{2pc} {\centering
 \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne \large \@chapapp{} \Thechapter \par
 \vspace{10\p@} \fi 
  \def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
  \large\bf \uppercase\expandafter{#1}\par
 \nobreak \vspace{20\p@}} }
%
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{ \vspace*{2pc} {\centering
 \large\bf \uppercase\expandafter{#1}\par
 \nobreak \vspace{20\p@}} }
%
\def\chapter{%
   \printchapternotes
   \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
   % \thispagestyle{empty}%
   \global\@topnum\z@
   \@afterindenttrue
   % \let\\\relax
   \secdef\@chapter\@schapter}
%
%  Complication is added here to allow line breaks
%  in the chapter titles (via \\).
%
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \refstepcounter{chapter}
  \typeout{<<\thechapter>>}
  {\def\\{ }  % allow \\ in title
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect
     \numberline{\@chapapp\ \thechapter:}#1}}\else
  {\def\\{ }  % allow \\ in title
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}\fi
 \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}
 \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{5\p@}}
 \if@twocolumn
  \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]
  \else \@makechapterhead{#2}
  \@afterheading \fi}
\def\@schapter#1{\if@twocolumn \@topnewpage[\@makeschapterhead{#1}]
  \else \@makeschapterhead{#1}
  \@afterheading\fi}
%
%  Section headings
%
\renewcommand\section{%
  \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
       {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
       {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
       {\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\reset@font\normalsize\bfseries\slshape}}
\renewcommand\subsection{%
  \@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
       {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
       {\reset@font\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{%
  \@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
       {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
       {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
       {\reset@font\normalsize\mdseries\itshape}}

% part
\renewcommand\l@part[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{75\p@}%
    \@dottedtocline{0}{\z@}{\@tempdima}{#1}{#2}%
  \fi}

%
%  Provide for `Chapter ' in the toc
%  (increase \@tempdima)
%
\renewcommand\l@chapter[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\m@ne
    \addpenalty{-\@highpenalty}%
    \vskip 1.0em \@plus\p@
    \setlength\@tempdima{75\p@}%
    \@dottedtocline{0}{\z@}{\@tempdima}{#1}{#2}%
  \fi}

% 
% extra space between toc entries
%
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip -\baselineskip % \@plus.2\p@%
    \vskip 1.2\baselineskip
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}

%
% ------ Special captions ---------------------
%
% \caption[]{text} produces normal caption and numbering
% \caption(-){(continued)} produces `(continued)' caption and 
%        same-as-last caption number
% \caption(x)[]{text} produces lettered caption.  1.1a, 1.1b, ...
%        If (x) is (a) or (A) then caption number is incremented,
%        else it is same numbered.

\def\thecaptionletter{}
\newif\ifcaptiontotoc\captiontotoctrue

\def\caption{\@ifnextchar({\@specialcaption}{\@normalcaption}}

\def\@normalcaption{\refstepcounter\@captype \@dblarg{\@caption\@captype}}
\def\@specialcaption(#1){%
  \def\thecaptionletter{#1}%
  \captiontotocfalse
  \if#1-\def\thecaptionletter{}\fi
  \if#1a\refstepcounter\@captype\captiontotoctrue\fi
  \if#1A\refstepcounter\@captype\captiontotoctrue\fi
  \@dblarg{\@caption\@captype}}

\long\def\@caption#1[#2]#3{\par
  \ifcaptiontotoc
    \addcontentsline{\csname
    ext@#1\endcsname}{#1}{\protect\numberline{\csname
    the#1\endcsname}{\ignorespaces #2}}%
  \fi
  \begingroup
    \@parboxrestore
    \def\baselinestretch{1.0}
    \normalsize  % UW grad school doesn't allow \footnotesize
    \@makecaption{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname
        \thecaptionletter}{\ignorespaces #3}\par
  \endgroup}

\def\@listI{\leftmargin\leftmargini \parsep 7\p@ plus 3\p@ minus 1\p@\topsep
 12\p@ plus 5\p@ minus 6\p@\itemsep 7\p@ plus 3\p@ minus 1\p@}


%
%  ----  Facing pages and double-page figures and tables
%
%  \begin{fullpage} ... \end{fullpage}
%  \begin{leftfullpage} ... \end{leftfullpage}
%  \begin{xtrafullpage} ... \end{xtrafullpage}

\newif\if@LP \@LPfalse
\newif\if@XP \@XPfalse

\newbox\@@wholepage
\def\fullpage{\setbox\@@wholepage=\vbox\bgroup}
\def\endfullpage{\egroup\dp\@@wholepage\z@
   \vbox to\textheight{\vss\unvbox\@@wholepage\vss}}
\def\leftfullpage{\setbox\@@wholepage=\vbox\bgroup}
\def\endleftfullpage{\egroup\dp\@@wholepage\z@
   \vbox to\textheight{\vss\unvbox\@@wholepage\vss}\global\@LPtrue}

\if@twoside
   \typeout{Formatting for twoside printing.}
   \let\xtrafullpage\fullpage
   \let\endxtrafullpage\endfullpage
\else
   \typeout{Formatting for oneside printing.}
   \def\xtrafullpage{\setbox\@@wholepage=\vbox\bgroup}
   \def\endxtrafullpage{\egroup\dp\@@wholepage\z@
      \vbox to\textheight{\vss\unvbox\@@wholepage\vss}\global\@XPtrue}
\fi

\let\oldend@float\end@float
\def\end@float{%
  \if@LP\global\@namedef{LP:\expandafter\string\@currbox}{L}%
  \else \global\@namedef{LP:\expandafter\string\@currbox}{z}%
  \fi
  \if@XP\global\@namedef{XP:\expandafter\string\@currbox}{X}%
  \else \global\@namedef{XP:\expandafter\string\@currbox}{z}%
  \fi
  \global\@LPfalse
  \global\@XPfalse
  \oldend@float
}


\if@twoside

% reject a left-side float that appears on an odd page
 \let\old@xtryfc\@xtryfc
 \def\@xtryfc #1{%
   \expandafter\if\csname LP:\string#1\endcsname L%
      % \typeout{facing page in xtryfc}%
      \ifodd\count0\global\@colht\z@
          \typeout{I moved a leftpage float from page \the\count0.}%
      \fi\fi
    \old@xtryfc #1}

\else

\def\unstep@page{\addtocounter{page}{-1}}

% flip a facing page caption
 \let\@oldwtryfc\@wtryfc
 \def\@wtryfc #1{%
  \expandafter\if\csname LP:\string#1\endcsname L\gdef\LP@page{}%
      \typeout{Encountered a facing page.}%
   \fi
  \expandafter\if\csname XP:\string#1\endcsname X\gdef\XP@page{}%
      \typeout{Encountered an extra page.}%
   \fi
   \@oldwtryfc #1}

 \let\old@outputpage\@outputpage
 \def\@outputpage{%
   \begingroup
   \@ifundefined{LP@page}
     {\let\@themargin\oddsidemargin \let\@thehead\@oddhead}
     {\let\@themargin\evensidemargin \let\@thehead\@evenhead
       \typeout{Printing a left-hand one-side page.}%
       \global\let\LP@page\relax
      }
   \@ifundefined{XP@page}
     {}
     {\let\@thehead\@empty \let\@thefoot\@empty
       \typeout{Printing an extra page.}%
       \global\let\XP@page\relax
       \aftergroup\unstep@page
      }
   \old@outputpage\endgroup
 }
\fi

%
%  ----  Preliminary pages  ---------------------------
%
\def\prelimpages{ % sets page numbering for the preliminary pages
   \pagestyle{empty} % will be {plain} at start of toc
   \pagenumbering{roman}
   \setcounter{page}{1}
   \footskip 30\p@ % allowance for the roman page numbers
    \advance\textheight by-\footskip  
   }
%
%      (The following macros are used once and discarded)
%
%  Title page
%
%  (Defaults are for dissertation.  See \MasterThesis below.)
%
\def\Title#1{\gdef\@Title{#1}}
\def\Author#1{\gdef\@Author{#1}}
\def\Year#1{\gdef\@Year{#1}}  \Year{\year}
\def\Degree#1{\gdef\@Degree{#1}} \Degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\def\Program#1{\gdef\@Program{#1}} \Program{your program here}
%
\def\School#1{\gdef\@School{#1}} \School{University of Washington}
\def\GSchool#1{\gdef\@GSchool{#1}} \GSchool{Graduate School}
\def\Degreetext#1{\gdef\@Degreetext{#1}} 
  \Degreetext{A dissertation\\ submitted in partial fulfillment of the\\requirements for the degree of}
\def\Programtext#1{\gdef\@Programtext{#1}}  
       \Programtext{Program Authorized to Offer Degree: }

\def\textofCommittee#1{\gdef\@textofCommittee{#1}}  
       \textofCommittee{Reading Committee: }
\def\textofDate#1{\gdef\@textofDate{#1}}  \textofDate{Date}

\def\textofChair#1{\gdef\@textofChair{#1}}
       \textofChair{Chair of the Supervisory Committee: }

\newcount\@Chair \@Chair0
\def\Chair#1#2#3{
  \global\@namedef{C:\expandafter\the\@Chair}{#1}
  \global\@namedef{T:\expandafter\the\@Chair}{#2}
  \global\@namedef{D:\expandafter\the\@Chair}{#3}
  \ifnum\@Chair>0\textofChair{Co-Chairs of the Supervisory Committee:}\fi
  \global\advance\@Chair by1}


\newcount\@Sign\@Sign0
\def\Signature#1{
  \global\@namedef{S:\expandafter\the\@Sign}{#1}
  \global\advance\@Sign by1}


\def\copyrightpage{                   % Prints the copyright page
    \vspace{7pc}
    \begin{center}
      \par\vskip\z@ plus4fill\relax
      \copyright Copyright \@Year
      \par
      \@Author
      \par\vskip\z@ plus2fill\relax
    \end{center}
  \let\copyrightpage\relax\relax}

\def\titlepage{                   % Prints the title page
    \cleardoublepage
    \vspace{7pc}
    \begin{center}
      {\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont\Large
      \lineskip 3ex
      \@Title\par}
      \par\vskip\z@ plus4fill\relax
      \@Author
      \par\vskip\z@ plus4fill\relax
      {\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
      \@Degreetext\par}
      \par\vskip\z@ plus2fill\relax
      \@Degree
      \par\vskip\z@ plus2fill\relax
      \@School
      \par\vskip\z@ plus1fill\relax
      \@Year
      \par\vskip\z@ plus4fill\relax

      % signers
      \@textofCommittee \par 
      \count1=0
      \@whilenum \count1<\@Chair \do
       {\vskip12\p@ \baselineskip12pt
        \csname C:\the\count1\endcsname, Chair
        \advance\count1 by1}
      \count1=0
      \@whilenum \count1<\@Sign \do
       {\vskip12\p@ \baselineskip12pt
        \csname S:\the\count1\endcsname
        \advance\count1 by1}

      \par\vskip\z@ plus4fill\relax
       {\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
      \@Programtext \par \@Program\par}
      \par\vskip\z@ plus1fill\relax
    \end{center}
     \vspace{2pc}\relax
  \let\titlepage\relax}


%
%   Abstract
%
%  normal parameters
\def\textofAbstract#1{\gdef\@textofAbstract{#1}}  \textofAbstract{Abstract}

\newsavebox\abs@savebox% (\abs@savebox compliments of blerner@cs.washington.edu)
\long\def\abstract#1{
   \cleardoublepage
   \begin{center}
      \@School
      \par\vskip1pc
      {\bf\@textofAbstract}%
      \par\vskip1pc
      {\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont \@Title \par}
      \par\vskip1pc
      \@Author
      \par\vskip1pc
       {\def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
      \@textofChair
      \par 
      \count1=0
      \@whilenum \count1<\@Chair \do
       {% \vskip12\p@ \baselineskip12pt
        \csname T:\the\count1\endcsname\ \csname C:\the\count1\endcsname
        \par \csname D:\the\count1\endcsname\par\vskip6\p@
        \advance\count1 by1}
       \par}
      \par\vskip1pc
   \end{center}
   \if@twoside
    \begingroup % have to set multiple abstract pages 1-sided
    \def\@blankpage{\if\@@blankpage B
            \setbox\abs@savebox\box255\shipout\vbox{}\setbox255\box\abs@savebox
            \global\advance\count\z@ by1\fi
            \global\def\@@blankpage{B}}
    \def\@@blankpage{A}
    \output=\expandafter{\expandafter\@blankpage\the\output}
   \fi
   #1
   \vfill\clearpage
   \if@twoside\endgroup\fi
   \let\abstract\relax}
%
%
%   Table of contents (right side page) (always page `i')
%
%
\def\textofToC#1{\gdef\@textofToC{#1}}  \textofToC{Table of Contents}
\def\tableofcontents{\cleardoublepage
   \chapter*{\@textofToC\@mkboth{}{}}
   \pagestyle{plain}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \setcounter{page}{1}
   \hbox to\textwidth{\hfill Page}
   {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
    \def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
   \@starttoc{toc}
    }
   }
%
%   List of figures
%

\def\textofLoF#1{\gdef\@textofLoF{#1}}  \textofLoF{List of Figures}
\def\listoffigures{\chapter*{\@textofLoF\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofLoF}
   \hbox to\textwidth{Figure Number \hfill Page}
   {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
    \def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
   \@starttoc{lof}
    }
   }
%
%   List of tables
%
\def\textofLoT#1{\gdef\@textofLoT{#1}}  \textofLoT{List of Tables}
\def\listoftables{\chapter*{\@textofLoT\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofLoT}
   \hbox to\textwidth{Table Number \hfill Page}
   {\let\footnotemark\relax  % in case one is in the title
    \def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
   \@starttoc{lot}
    }
   }
%
%  Bibliography
%
\def\textofBIB#1{\gdef\@textofBIB{#1}}  \textofBIB{Bibliography}
\def\thebibliography#1{\chapter*{\@textofBIB\@mkboth{}{}}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\@textofBIB}
 \list
 {[\arabic{enumi}]}{\settowidth\labelwidth{[#1]}\leftmargin\labelwidth
 \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
 \usecounter{enumi}}
 \def\newblock{\hskip .11em plus .33em minus .07em}
 \sloppy\clubpenalty4000\widowpenalty4000
 \def\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
 \sfcode`\.=1000\relax}

%
%   Acknowledgments
%
\def\textofAck#1{\gdef\@textofAck{#1}}  \textofAck{Acknowledgments}
\long\def\acknowledgments#1{\chapter*{\@textofAck\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   #1\par
   \vfill
   \let\acknowledgments\relax}

%
%   Dedication
%
\def\textofDed#1{\gdef\@textofDed{#1}}  \textofDed{Dedication}
\long\def\dedication#1{\chapter*{\@textofDed\@mkboth{}{}}
   \thispagestyle{plain}
   #1\par
   \vfill
   \let\dedication\relax}

%
%   Vita
%
\def\textofVita#1{\gdef\@textofVita{#1}}  \textofVita{Vita}
\long\def\vita#1{\chapter*{\@textofVita\@mkboth{}{}}
   #1\par
   \vfill
   \let\vita\relax}

%
%   Gratis definition of a glossary environment
%
\renewenvironment{glossary}
  {\begin{list}{}{\setlength\itemindent{\parindent}
   \def\makelabel##1{\footnotesize\uppercase{##1:}\hfill}}}
  {\end{list}}

% End of the thesis style
```

These two code blocks should be sufficient to reproduce the indexing problems that I've been having.  Thanks in advance for your help on this!!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is the above code part of the thesis template from your university? The captions facilities seem to be redefined and it seems to interfere with `subfig` or `subfloat` packages, resulting in doubled `\refstepcounter` calls.

Comment: Correct, that is an accurate description of the problem.  And, yes; above code is from my university's thesis template.  Still working on the MWE.  Thanks for your super prompt responses!

Comment: Christian,  I've posted the MWE that reproduces the indexing problem I  originally posted about.  As instructed by 'help', I've edited the original post to include the additions being that they are new material.

Comment: The posted `.cls` file is either wrong or at least incomplete.

Comment: I've edited the post to include the full .cls file.  I'm not familiar with document-class coding and probably missed some required command lines when I cut and pasted the section for the previous post.

Comment: It still does not compile, since it complains about the redefinition of `\caption` etc. Do you really need this redefined caption styles, something which `(sub)caption` can do probably do for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When all else fails, do `\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`:

```
\documentclass [11pt, twoside] {uwthesis}[2012/06/19]

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}  % Print the chapter and sections to the toc

\usepackage{alltt}  %
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow,bigdelim}
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage[xspace]{ellipsis}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newenvironment{demo}
  {\begin{alltt}\leftskip3em
     \def\\{\ttfamily\char`\\}%
     \def\{{\ttfamily\char`\{}%
     \def\}{\ttfamily\char`\}}}
  {\end{alltt}}

% metafont font.  If logo not available, use the second form
%
% \font\mffont=logosl10 scaled\magstep1
\let\mffont=\sf
% --- end-of-sample-stuff ---

\begin{document}

%
% ==========      Text pages
%

\textpages

%\include{Figures_SubcaptionsTest}
%\include{Figures_CaptionsTest}

% ================== figure 1, no subfigures
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics{//SampleFig.eps}
    \caption{Sample caption for figure 1.}
    \label{fig:Figure1}
\end{figure}

% ================= figure 2,  includes subfigures
\begin{figure}[h!p]
  \subfloat[First subfigure sample.]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{//SampleSubfig.eps}%
    \label{fig:FirstSampleSubFig}%
  }\hfill
  \subfloat[Second subfigure sample.]{%
    \includegraphics[width=.45\textwidth]{//SampleSubfig.eps}%
    \label{fig:SecondSampleSubFig}%
  }
  \caption{Sample composite caption for figure 2.}
  \label{fig:Figure2}
\end{figure}

% ================== figure 3, no subfigures
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics{//SampleFig.eps}
    \caption{Sample caption for figure 3.}
    \label{fig:Figure3}
\end{figure}

\ref{fig:Figure2}

\subref{fig:FirstSampleSubFig}

\ref{fig:FirstSampleSubFig}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this fix on a few sub-figures in my thesis.  The compiler no longer warns against redefining `\caption` and figures (and sub-figures) are numbered correctly.  Though I have many figures to re-code, this fix solves my problems.

Comment: @thugwithyoyo Still `subfig` might have some problems with `hyperref`; but it's better than nothing, isn't it?

Comment: Indeed.  I've since learned that hyperref supports document hyperlinks; I had mistakenly thought it performed general cross-referencing operations in latex.  Since I do not intend to use hyperlinks in my thesis, this should not be an issue for me.  As you and Christian pointed out, my indexing problems seemed to be caused by using `\caption{}` in conjuction with my school's thesis template.  Many thanks!