# plotting side by side two subfigures in a one figure in an llncs class file

Tags: pgfplots, subfloats

I want to plot two figures in the same line. I'm also using the `llncs` Springer class file [found here](https://www.springer.com/computer/lncs?SGWID=0-164-6-793341-0) for my document.

I have these two figures:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar,
  symbolic x coords={x1, x2, x3},
  xtick={x1, x2, x3},
ytick={5, 4, 10},
  xticklabel style={rotate=-90},
nodes near coords,
  ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
width = 6.9cm,
  legend pos= north east]
\addplot [black] coordinates{(x1, 5) (x2, 4) (x3, 10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
{\footnotesize $\bf Fig. 10.$  The results using gh algo}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
      \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
      symbolic x coords={x1, x2, x3},
      xtick={x1, x2, x3},
    ytick={4, 7, 23},
      xticklabel style={rotate=-90},
    nodes near coords,
      ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    width = 6.9cm,
      legend pos= north east]
    \addplot [black] coordinates{(x1, 4) (x2, 7) (x3, 23)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    {\footnotesize $\bf Fig. 10.$  The results using er algo}
    \end{figure}
```

When I am plotting these two figures like, I always get the second figure below the first figure. What I want is to plot side by side the two figures. How can I modify my code?

Any help will be very appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}\small
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, 
symbolic x coords={x1, x2, x3},
  xtick={x1, x2, x3},
ytick={5, 4, 10},
  xticklabel style={rotate=-90},
nodes near coords,
  ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
width = 6.9cm,
  legend pos= north east]
\addplot [black] coordinates{(x1, 5) (x2, 4) (x3, 10)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{The results using gh algo}\label{fig:10a}
\end{minipage}%
%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[ybar,
      symbolic x coords={x1, x2, x3},
      xtick={x1, x2, x3},
    ytick={4, 7, 23},
      xticklabel style={rotate=-90},
    nodes near coords,
      ylabel={Accuracy (\%)},
    width = 6.9cm,
      legend pos= north east]
    \addplot [black] coordinates{(x1, 4) (x2, 7) (x3, 23)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\subcaption{The results using er algo}\label{fig:10b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Comparison of two alorithms}\label{fig:10}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

`figure` is a float environment, so you should use only one environment and put the two plots inside it. you don't need a `footnote` then , but, a caption for each plot and a caption for the whole figure. Using the `subcaption` [package](http://ctan.asis.io/macros/latex/contrib/caption/subcaption.pdf), this can be easy.

Actually, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side) is similar and can help, but here, you need two plots in a single figure, so the `subcaption` package may be your choice.

**Update**

Since the `llnc.cls` has some incompatibilities with the `caption` package, one should add the option `\captionsetup{compatibility=false}` in the preamble. This was mentioned by the `subcaption` package author in an answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/subcaption-package-compatibility-issue).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! why I am getting error with the subcaption package ?

Comment: @Christina Do you use other packages for captions? and what is the error message?

Comment: Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected,
(caption)                usage of the caption package is not recommended.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

)

! Package subcaption Error: This package can't be used in cooperation
(subcaption)                with the subfigure package.

Comment: I am using these packages:\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.3} 
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

Comment: Furthermore I am using \documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}

Comment: The subfigure package is deprecated, use `subfig` instead. I updated my answer using `subfig`.

Comment: I got the same error. I am not able to use the subcaption package

Comment: Aha!!, you didn't mention `llncs.cls` in your question, I'll give you another solution ...

Comment: @Christina Please see my update!