# Subfigure does not work for Springer journal

Tags: floats, subfloats

I would like to ask how to compile subfigure command in Springer Journals. Here is my code:

```
 \begin{figure*}[htp]   
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
    \centering            
\includegraphics[width=.65\textwidth]{../latex/figure/rev_n.pdf}
        \caption{An example of }\label{rev}
     \end{subfigure}
~
 \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.35\textwidth}
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{../latex/figure/rev_sol_n.pdf}
        \caption{An scheme of }\label{rev_sol} 
   \end{subfigure}

        \caption{Illustration of }\label{bs1}
\end{figure*}
```

Link for springer latex template:https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates.

Once removed subfigure linewidth (`\begin{subfigure}[t]%{0.65\textwidth}`), it is possible to compile the file. However, gives different figure number not subfigure number. Is there any way to command some codes to run the file with subfigure?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2)  please post the full minimal document, and post the error message you get. As you question sits here, we don't know if you have loaded anything that provides `subfigure`, I don't think Springers  provides it by default.

Comment: A possible solution is to add `\usepackage{subcaption}` to your preamble (between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`). To answer the question it would also be helpful to know which error message you currently get when trying to compile the document.

Comment: I already have \usepackage{subcaption}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When compiling your document you should get the following error:

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
(caption)                in compatibility mode.
```

This is because the `caption` package isn't adapted to the `svjour3` document class. It detects unknown caption code and therefore switches itself into the "compatibility mode", trying to be as compatible as possible to the `caption` package v1.x from 1995.

The `subcaption` package is relying on new features offered by `caption` v3.x, and therefore refuse to work in this environment.

Possible solution: Try the `subfig` package instead which isn't relying on `caption`:

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

An example document, derived from the template:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}          % twocolumn
%
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\title{Insert your title here}
\subtitle{Do you have a subtitle?\\ If so, write it here}

%\titlerunning{Short form of title}        % if too long for running head

\author{First Author         \and
        Second Author %etc.
}

%\authorrunning{Short form of author list} % if too long for running head

\institute{F. Author \at
              first address \\
              Tel.: +123-45-678910\\
              Fax: +123-45-678910\\
              \email{fauthor@example.com}           %  \\
%             \emph{Present address:} of F. Author  %  if needed
           \and
           S. Author \at
              second address
}

\date{Received: date / Accepted: date}
% The correct dates will be entered by the editor

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Insert your abstract here. Include keywords, PACS and mathematical
subject classification numbers as needed.
\keywords{First keyword \and Second keyword \and More}
\end{abstract}

\section{Subfigures}

\begin{figure*}[htp]
   \subfloat[An example of ]{\label{rev}
      \includegraphics[width=.65\textwidth]{../latex/figure/rev_n.pdf}}
~
   \subfloat[An scheme of ]{\label{rev_sol}
      \includegraphics[width=.35\textwidth]{../latex/figure/rev_sol_n.pdf}}

   \caption{Illustration of }\label{bs1}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work. I already have \usepackage[caption=false]{sub fig}.

Comment: @ruz What exactly do you mean with "does not work". What error message do you get? Please note that the `subfig` package offers a different syntax than the `subcaption` package.

Comment: @nuz I just added an example document to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! This solves the problem for the `ws-ijbc` class.

Comment: The answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31906/subcaption-package-compatibility-issue fixes this for me (`\captionsetup{compatibility=false}`) with the caveat this might change formatting