# Is there an easy way to use package 'subcaption' with SN journal style?

Tags: subcaption, journal

Is there an easy way to use package 'subcaption' with SN journal style?

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}       % onecolumn (second format)
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

presents me with a message: The 'subcaption' package does not work correctly(caption) in compatibility mode.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/439994/134144 might be interesting.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31927/149028 is also relevant.